# Swift-JWT decoding issue

Tags: swift, jwt, encode

I am using the Swift-JWT Cocoapod file, when I try to encode a particular claim struct, it gives me a cryptogram, when I check in this cryptogram on the https://jwt.io/ website, it is decoding successfully but the order of the claim struct object is changing. I don't know what to do right now?

any suggestions much appreciate

Note:- I need when we are going encode of the claim struct, that same struct need to decode with the same order.

for example, This is my claim struct with using private key, I am encoding the data

```
ClaimsRequest(
deviceId: "1D9B98D1-63FE-466B-99CB-A2CBDEB1612F", 
amount: "32.00", 
currency: "MUR", 
debtorAccount: "1234567890", 
creditorAccount: "255252522", 
endToEndId: "CMCLMUM020220202000019", 
consentId: "88379")
```

privateKey:

Printing description of privateKey:
"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"

```
var myJWT = JWT(claims: myClaims)
do {
 if let privateKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: privateKey) {
      let jwtSigner = JWTSigner.rs512(privateKey: privateKeyData)
           let signedJWT = try myJWT.sign(using: jwtSigner)
            return signedJWT
    }
}
```

it is given cryptogram of the data

Printing description of cryptogram:
▿ Optional

- some : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJhbW91bnQiOiIzMi4wMCIsImRldmljZUlkIjoiMUQ5Qjk4RDEtNjNGRS00NjZCLTk5Q0ItQTJDQkRFQjE2MTJGIiwiY3JlZGl0b3JBY2NvdW50IjoiMjU1MjUyNTIyIiwiZW5kVG9FbmRJZCI6IkNNQ0xNVU0wMjAyMjAyMDIwMDAwMTkiLCJkZWJ0b3JBY2NvdW50IjoiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MCIsImN1cnJlbmN5IjoiTVVSIiwiY29uc2VudElkIjoiODgzNzkifQ.gjI_il7eu_topH2-i_UY_vFrD3rGpMe5a8R-mbO48MbKYaVcIJuNO4QxaqBR-nltBn5fPnZfWqxta6jqFJ4-W1CDIIVTDNI6vGZn8UTgn8TkZ21VA1wNb0Os067dGrDHtzlvJwrwOhLD2cND5F_YbN7v_cYMJEkTDKgTyi6w4HW3jqZPzMfEMfjQ36jlM8KlCf1_XeZ1V-OzNOmBhc6ToErHYJbM61fmV2DjVShGVqZ2dFu1Myw1FpaVvbp8YTA6_POq1kk3p8Ml6s6o0SQ3-c4cZ6f08z16fGGO7K-Tn7fDenZgX8oRQ0YvV3LeGzbbYgGFaqES_7KK1txLPOqTww"

So, when I paste this cryptogram in JWT.io it gives decoding Object, here you can see order changing of claim struct.

```
{
  "amount": "32.00",
  "deviceId": "1D9B98D1-63FE-466B-99CB-A2CBDEB1612F",
  "creditorAccount": "255252522",
  "endToEndId": "CMCLMUM020220202000019",
  "debtorAccount": "1234567890",
  "currency": "MUR",
  "consentId": "88379"
}
```

Comment: Without any details, it's probably not possible to answer this. Can you show your code, how you encode and decode the token and also an example of the data, what you expect and what you actually get?

Comment: @jps as per your comment i added some code, please check and help

Comment: @jps any comment ??